# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tree' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an org chart and looking to incorporate this library https://github.com/unicef/react-org-chart

It works on their demo but when i try to incorporate into my own app, i'll get the following error

**Error: index.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tree' of undefined**

I tried to console log the property tree and tree is already defined as shown below.

Would anyone know if it's a library issue or i'm not incorporating it correctly?

```
{id: 1, person: {…}, hasChild: true, hasParent: false, isHighlight: true, …}
children: [{…}]
hasChild: true
hasParent: false
id: 1
isHighlight: true
person:
avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/spbroma/128.jpg"
department: ""
id: 1
name: "Jane Doe"
title: "CEO"
totalReports: 1
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

**Here's the sample code (ExtOrgChart.jsx) for reference**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import OrgChart from '@unicef/react-org-chart';

const tree = {
  id: 1,
  person: {
    id: 1,
    avatar: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/spbroma/128.jpg',
    department: '',
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    title: 'CEO',
    totalReports: 1,
  },
  hasChild: true,
  hasParent: false,
  isHighlight: true,
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      person: {
        id: 2,
        avatar: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/spbroma/128.jpg',
        department: '',
        name: 'John Foo',
        title: 'CTO',
        totalReports: 0,
      },
      hasChild: false,
      hasParent: true,
      isHighlight: false,
      children: [],
    }],
};

function ExtOrgChart() {
  console.log(tree);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OrgChart tree={tree} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExtOrgChart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the lib itself has some issues - https://github.com/unicef/react-org-chart

Upon further research and attempts (E.g. Setting D3 to a specific version) it will still not display. Would suggest trying out other libraries such as https://github.com/dabeng/react-orgchart which might be easier to implement.